# How to print the error messages generated by Junit to text file

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to find a solution as to: how to print the error messages generated by Junit to a text file.

Comment: Use logging? You may be asking this because you are running JUnit through Eclipse's JUnit support. You need to run it from code you've written, then you won't have trouble finding a way.

Answer (score 0):

Catch/Generate  the Error message and write out it to any file.

`new FileWriter(new File("myFile.txt")).write(errorMessage)